# Key converting between different languages

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net

How can I get the keyboard key between different languages? E.g. the (A) key at quwerty keyboard equals (some letter) in another keyboard. How can I get that key.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question isn't entirely clear. When you say "another keyboard" do you mean a different piece of hardware than a QWERTY keyboard? Where that different hardware has a key with a particular label ('A') on it in a different position than the key with that same label ('A') has on a QWERTY keyboard (next to leftmost on the third row). In which case I'd take your question to mean "what key is located at the next to leftmost in the third row on the different keyboard?"

If that's the question then the answer can be determined by querying windows (`GetKeyboardLayout` or .NET equivalent if there is one) for the "keyboard layout". You get back an input locale id. The input locale id can be translated to a locale using this [table](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/goglobal/bb895996.aspx).

Using the locale you can then look up pictorial diagrams of keyboard layouts [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/goglobal/bb964651). Select a locale from the drop down list.

EDIT 12/29/15

To do this programmatically: one way would be to encode the pictorial diagrams of the keyboard layouts you are interested in. Keyboards generate "scan codes". So on a US keyboard layout, scan code 31 corresponds to the A key. In this manner you could build a table for all possible scan codes for US layout. And do the same for French Canadian, and then French Swiss, etc. Then you can translate A on US keyboard layout to scan code 31 to whatever that maps to on the other keyboard layouts.

This is based on the assumption that scan codes stay the same on keyboards and just the labels on the keys change. I'm sure there are limits to this assumption. For example if you google "chinese keyboard" and look at images, you'll see some keyboards with many more keys than a traditional US style keyboard (which have approximately 100 keys).

However, the tables I'm suggesting are most likely already available within Windows. Somewhere in the input stack Windows has to translate scan codes to characters. I suggest googling for more info on Windows keyboard layouts and APIs that deal with "input locales".

Comment: That is a great answer. But, can i do this by code? If I've got the keyboardlayout. How to convert keys (get key position then, convert it)?

Comment: Editing answer to respond to this question.